# Получение элемента из div с помощью цикла while

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно перебрать все элементы класса `div-11` и вывести их значения с пробелом в `out-11`

Помогите найти ошибку когда я нажимаю кнопку выводит только `one one one one`;

а должно `one 3 4 two`;

и да решить нужно с помощью цикла `while`

```js
function t11() {
  let out = document.querySelector('.out-11');
  let a = '';
  let i = 0;
  let div = document.querySelectorAll('.div-11');
  div = div[i].innerHTML;
  while (i < div.length) {

    a += div + ' ';
    i++
  }
  out.innerHTML = a;
}

document.querySelector('.b-11').onclick = t11;
```

```html
<div class="div-11">one</div>
<div class="div-11">3</div>
<div class="div-11">4</div>
<div class="div-11">two</div>
<button class="button-primary b-11">Task-11</button>
<div class="out-11"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let div = document.querySelectorAll('.div-11');
while ( i < div.length) {
    a += div[i].innerHTML + ' ';
    i++
}
out.innerHTML = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кому пригодится — другой подход:

```
function t11() {
    let div11 = document.querySelectorAll('.div-11');
    let out11 = document.querySelector('.out-11');
    for(let i = 0; i < div11.length; i ++)  {
        out11.textContent += div11[i].textContent + ' ';
    }
}
document.querySelector('.b-11').onclick = t11;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]